# Send a PDF file to telegram using PL/SQL- UTL_HTTP code

Tags: oracle, plsql, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to send a pdf document and a small description about it from my server to a Telegram group using a Telegram bot user. I'm able to send a document by itself using the method /sendDocument. However, that is not exactly what I want. I wonder is that even possible to do ?

The actual output message is "ORA-29263: HTTP protocol error."

```sql
declare
  l_attachment blob;
  l_newline varchar2(50) := chr(13) || chr(10);
  lco_boundary constant varchar2(30) := '----=*#abc1234321cba#*=';

  l_http_request utl_http.req;
  l_request_body clob;
  l_request_body_length number;

  l_http_response utl_http.resp;
  l_response_header_name varchar2(256);
  l_response_header_value varchar2(1024);
  l_response_body varchar2(32767);

  l_offset number := 1;
  l_amount number := 2000;
  l_buffer varchar2(2000);
  postData clob;
  p_id varchar2(50) := '********';
begin

select invoce into l_attachment  from some_table;

  l_request_body := l_newline
|| '--' || lco_boundary || l_newline
|| 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"; filename="file.pdf"' || l_newline
|| 'Content-Type: application/pdf' || l_newline
|| l_newline
|| apex_web_service.blob2clobbase64(l_attachment) || l_newline
|| '--' || lco_boundary || l_newline
|| 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="document"' || l_newline
|| l_newline
|| 'file.pdf' || l_newline
|| '--' || lco_boundary || l_newline
|| 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MAX_FILE_SIZE"' || l_newline
|| l_newline
|| '4000000' || l_newline
|| '--' || lco_boundary || '--';

  dbms_output.put_line('Request body>');
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_lob.substr(l_request_body, 4000, 1));

  l_request_body_length := dbms_lob.getlength(l_request_body);

  utl_http.set_wallet('file:/u02/oracle/upload/WALLET_TELEGRAM/', '******');

  l_http_request := utl_http.begin_request(
                      url => 'https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY_KEY>/sendDocument',
                      method => 'POST',
                      http_version => 'HTTP/1.1'
                    );

  postData := postData || 'chat_id=' || p_id || '&';    
  postData := postData || 'document=';

  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary="' || lco_boundary || '"');
  utl_http.set_header(l_http_request, 'Content-Length', l_request_body_length);
  utl_http.write_text(l_http_request, postData);

  while l_offset < l_request_body_length loop
    dbms_lob.read(l_request_body, l_amount, l_offset, l_buffer);
    utl_http.write_text(l_http_request, l_buffer);
    l_offset := l_offset + l_amount;
  end loop;

  l_http_response := utl_http.get_response(l_http_request);

  for i in 1 .. utl_http.get_header_count(l_http_response) loop
    utl_http.get_header(l_http_response, i, l_response_header_name, l_response_header_value);
l_response_header_value);
  end loop;

  utl_http.read_text(l_http_response, l_response_body, 32767);
  dbms_output.put_line(l_response_body);

  if l_http_request.private_hndl is not null then
    utl_http.end_request(l_http_request);
  end if;

  if l_http_response.private_hndl is not null then
    utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
  end if;
exception
  when others then
    if l_http_request.private_hndl is not null then
      utl_http.end_request(l_http_request);
    end if;

    if l_http_response.private_hndl is not null then
      utl_http.end_response(l_http_response);
    end if;

    raise;
end;
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What's the problem?

Comment: ORA-29273 is a generic failure message. I suggest you extend your exception handler section to call `UTL_HTTP.get_detailed_sqlerrm()` function and log the detailed error message. Probably you will realise what the problem is once you read it. If not you can edit your question to include this vital information. There's nothing more we can do to help you without further details.

Comment: Sorry.. this is my first post on stackoverflow. I am trying to send a document to telegram bot using pl/sql.

After execute the UTL_HTTP.get_detailed_sqlerrm() command, I got this message : "ORA-29263: HTTP protocol error"